# Increase duration time of dismissViewControllerAnimated()

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've been trying to figure out how increase the duration time of `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` but can't seem to find an answer in Apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:). My view controller appears with an animation from bottom to top and behaves in the reverse order when dismissed. I want the animation to be slower, say 0.5 sec, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use custom transitions for your view controller. Please have a look at this wonderful tutorial to get you started: http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/

Adding the major code here in case link gets removed in future:

Create a new class called `CustomPresentAnimationController` and make it a subclass of `NSObject`.
class CustomPresentAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

`UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol has two required methods which we’ll add next. Add the following methods to the class.

```
    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 2.5
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
    let finalFrameForVC = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(toViewController)
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    toViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(finalFrameForVC, 0, bounds.size.height)
    containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.5
        toViewController.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
        }, completion: {
            finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 1.0
    })}
```

With the animation controller completed, we need to link it to a storyboard segue.
Open the `ItemsTableViewController.swift` file and change the class declaration as shown.

```
class ItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
```

Add this inside this class to handle segue:

```
let customPresentAnimationController = CustomPresentAnimationController()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showAction" {
        let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Add the following `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` method to the class. This returns the instance of our custom animation controller.

```
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return customPresentAnimationController
}
```

**All credits to the original author of the article.**

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: In that case I think the only solution is to implement a custom animation.